# Openlayers add feature in Internet explorer memory issue

Tags: openlayers, internet-explorer

We have a map configuration, where at a certain zoom level we have to plot N number of features, ranging in hundreds to thousands, but on Internt Explorer, if the feature count is more than 2500, than there are memory issues. So, is it possible to plot the features on the map progressively in a manner, so that memory issues can be resolved?

Comment: Which version of OpenLayers are you using?

Comment: latest version v4.2.0